# Modify mouse cursor labels when dragging files into Java application

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, label

I'm debugging a standalone Java application that supports drag-and-drop of files from outside the program (say the OS's native file manager) onto the application.  This is all tested and working; we have a JList that accepts the drop actions and behaves appropriately.

Some platforms, notably Windows 7+, put little helpful text labels on your mouse cursor when you start dragging the files.  For example, dragging a file in Win7 defaults to "Move", if you then hold down the Control key it switches to "Copy", holding down shift+Control switches to "Link", etc, all before you release the mouse button.

It's been pointed out that these labels are a little misleading in our case, since our application is not actually moving, copying, or doing any such thing to the files.  Obviously we can't affect the labels as the user is still dragging the files out there around the monitor in arbitrary places, but we'd like to replace the label **once the dragging mouse enters the application**.  By that point, our `TransferHandler.canImport()` routine is firing.

Nothing in the Swing docs that I've read suggest that this is possible, but those have been pretty generic and high-level.  Can those labels be overridden by the application being dragged onto?  (Given that something like 90% of our userbase is on Windows, we're willing to accept Windows-only solutions; other platforms can just see the "Move" label or whatever.)

I've looked briefly at the current java.awt.Cursor when the mouse has reached the application, and even with a bunch of dragged files on the cursor and the label "Move" hanging off the bottom, it's still the default cursor.